# How to set 3d models in arCore plane without tapping

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to set a 3d model on a random part of the ARcore immediately when the plane is detected. Not sure of which method to use to setup.

```
addOnUpdateListener(this::onUpdate);

 private void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {
    if (numOfModels > 0) return;
    modelLoader1 = new ModelLoader(weakReference);
    Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
    Collection<Plane> planes = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane.class);
    for (Plane plane : planes) {
        if (plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
            addObject(Uri.parse("andy_dance.sfb"));
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void addObject(Uri model) {
    Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
    android.graphics.Point pt = getScreenCenter();
    List<HitResult> hits;
    if (frame != null) {
        hits = frame.hitTest(pt.x, pt.y);
        for (HitResult hit : hits) {
            Trackable trackable = hit.getTrackable();
            if (trackable instanceof Plane &&
                    ((Plane) trackable).isPoseInPolygon(hit.getHitPose())) {
                modelLoader1.loadModel(hit.createAnchor(), model);
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}

public void loadModel(Anchor anchor, Uri uri) {
    if (owner.get() == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity is null.  Cannot load model.");
        return;
    }
    ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(owner.get(), uri)
            .build()
            .handle((renderable, throwable) -> {
                MainActivity activity = owner.get();
                if (activity == null) {
                    return null;
                } else if (throwable != null) {
                    activity.onException(throwable);
                } else {
                    activity.addNodeToScene(anchor, renderable);
                }
                return null;
            });

    return;
}

public void addNodeToScene(Anchor anchor, ModelRenderable renderable) {
    numOfModels++;
    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
    TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
    node.setRenderable(renderable);
    node.setParent(anchorNode);
    node.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f));
    modelLoader1.setNumofLivesModel0(2);
    arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);

    setNodeListener(node, anchorNode, modelLoader1);
```

So far I am able to populate the screen with one model but at the center of the screen, we would like to set the model in the corner if possible for now

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the activity I have a new Vector3 object instantiated so I can use it for the 3d Models positioning later:

```
vector = new Vector3();
```

Figured it out by implementing a world anchor that ARCore recognizes as the phone's position:

```
AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode();
    anchorNode.setWorldPosition(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

With the AnchorNode set, we are able to position an object in the world knowing where it will actually be.

```
vector.set(randomCoordinates(true), randomCoordinates(false), -.7f);

AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode();
    TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
node.setRenderable(ModelRenderable);
node.setParent(anchorNode);
node.setWorldPosition(vector);
```

The arguments accepted for vector.set() are 3 floats which are x,y,z coordinates. In order to make 3d models show up infront of your camera, it is recommended for the x-coordinate to be between -.300 to .300, the y-coordinate to be between -.500 to .500, and the z-coordinate to be between -.7 to 1.